# Does tearDown get called if test case throws exception? (JUnit)

Tags: junit

I understand it gets called after each test method but can somebody explicitly tell me whether it gets called if the test methods throws an exception?

Comment: you could just write a test, throw an exception and find out for yourself

Comment: are you still JUnit 3, or are you on JUnit 4?

Comment: @reevesy, I could do that. But there is a difference between whether it gets run for one specific case and the contract between me and JUnit, isn't there?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html):

> All `@After` methods are guaranteed to run even if a `Before` or `Test` method throws an exception.

Comment: It's now 2021. Is this still true for JUnit 5?